# PHP ambiguous code with variable function names

Tags: php

Consider the following

```
Class someController {

    public static $layout = 'index';
}
```

Then in another scope

```
$layout = 'default';
$controller = 'someController';

if(property_exists($controller, 'layout')){
    $layout = $controller::$layout;
}
```

What will then be the content of `$layout`? Is it going to try to access `someController::$layout` or `someController::default`?

Comment: https://eval.in/302032 gives `someController::$layout` - although im confused as to why

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ yeah I tested it too out of curiosity, but there must be an explanation to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When PHP parses the code, the referencing of the static class variable takes preference over the standalone variable.

Edit: Infact, the parser does not even consider to think `$controller::$layout` has a reference to the `$layout` variable as it is using `::` as @Paul Crovella mentioned in the question comments.

Comment: Actually I just found out that to use the value of the local variable as a property name I need to use double dollar sign as in variable variables, which makes a lot of sense!

Comment: It should be noted that you can use variable variables to access a property with a variable (if that makes sense). In OPs scenario; `$default = 'layout'; echo $controller::${$layout}`